# Что является лучшим вариантом для эффективного выполнения непостоянных фоновых задач в ОС Android?

Tags: android, многопоточность

Для фонового выполнения задач в среде Android доступны 4 класса: `HandlerThread`, `Thread`, `IntentService`, `AsyncTask`. Использование какого класса эффективно для выполнения фоновых задач, если задачи возникают непостоянно?

Задачей в основном является получения информации из интернета. Из-за непостоянства задач непонятно какой класс использовать для достижения наилучшей эффективности.

`HandlerThread` хорош для выполнения частых запросов, но при редких - простой потока. `Thread` хорош при редких запросов, но при частых - падение производительности (создание объекта + резервирование необходимых ресурсов). `AsyncTask` аналогичен Thread. `IntentService` хорош для всех задач, но проблемы в производительности могут быть из-за частого запуска сервиса системой android.

Кто что может посоветовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вас скорее должен волновать вопрос нужно ли вам, чтобы работа завершилась до конца или особо не важно. Т.к. если вам крайне необходимо чтобы поток завершил свою работу, то однозначно - IntentService, если всё равно, то можете юзать AsyncTask, поверьте, лишнего процессорного времени он не жрёт